# Create csv file from a list in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following variables:

```
   id<- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'll')
   location<- list(c('newyork', 'boston'), c('london','paris'), NULL, c('mumbai'))

  df<- data.frame(id, location)
  write.csv(df, file='test.csv')
```

I want to create a csv file from the data frame but i am getting error as the location is a list? Any ideas on how i can do this in R?

This sort of thing data structure was expected, if csv doesn't allow for nested structure it might be problematic. How about xls or xlsx?

```
  id location
  A  c(newyork, boston)
  B  c(london, paris)
  C  Null 
  D  c('mumbai')
```

Comment: Can you show how you want the CSV to look for your given input? Generally CSVs don't allow for a nested structure, so we need to know what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Also, your first three lines of code don't run as you have put them here. Please correct them so there are no syntax errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It seems very strange that you want a flatfile with `c(newyork, boston)` as the value in a single field. You could easily use a tab-separated file to get around the problem of internal commas, or you could use JSON or XML if you need a nested structure. Or you could use RData if you just need to read it back into R... what is your goal?

Comment: I have a column where there is a list of universities where the students studied, I want to create a variable called foreignex if the students studied at foreign university, it will be 1 if they studied at Oxford university  and 0 if they have all education in US, as R studio lists only 1000 variables i cannot see the rest columns to code.

Comment: That seems to have nothing to do with writing data out to a CSV, or writing data to disk at all. And having the R syntax `c(` and `)` as part of the values will make further analysis more difficult if anything.

Comment: yep you are right,  i am trying to find all alternative way to code just inside R so i don't go back and forth between csv and R, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `paste` to combine elements in `location`. Then everything can be the same.

```
id<- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'll')
location<- list(c('newyork', 'boston'), c('london','paris'), NULL, c('mumbai'))
location = paste(location,sep = "")
df = data.frame(id,location)
write.csv(df, file='test.csv')
#> df
#  id               location
#1  A c("newyork", "boston")
#2  B   c("london", "paris")
#3  C                   NULL
#4 ll                 mumbai
```

The `csv` will look like below:

```
"","id","location"
"1","A","c(""newyork"", ""boston"")"
"2","B","c(""london"", ""paris"")"
"3","C","NULL"
"4","ll","mumbai"
```

You can cleanup further if you want

Comment: Not a valid CSV that has commas inside a single field

Comment: I did a similar approach but I used location<-as.character(location) for the third line.